# Why do we need filesystem block checksum?

Tags: disk, checksum

Each sector on the disk has its own ECC to detect (and can sometimes correct) data corruption.

[image]

Yet some filesystems like Btrfs and ZFS provide checksum for each of their data block. Is it really necessary? When the disk determine a sector is bad, the block that contains that sector should be considered bad too.

Comment: This doesn't prevent a RaspberryPi to corrupt its microSD on reboot and then have the microSD happily provide wrong (and randomly changing) data when reading the corrupted block. What's left? Something on a layer above (linux' dm-integrity, filesystem ...). I admit a raspberryPi is a wrong example to run ZFS.

Comment: "Is it really necessary?" – *Strict* answer: no. Many other filesystems don't provide checksums and we still use them; so it's not necessary. "Is it useful?" is a different question.